# OpenTK multiple GLControl with a single Context

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I`m working on a program which should have multiple views of a model. I would like to use multiple`GLControls` for that.

Is there any possibility to create multiple GLControl which use the same GraphicsContext?

I successfully created this on a multithreaded enviroment, but the contexts are not shared then. So I have to load the model for each context, which is bad.

My pseudocode for a single threaded enviroment looks something like this:

```
glControl1.MakeCurrent();
// Render here
glControl1.SwapBuffers();
glControl2.MakeCurrent();
// Render here too
glControl2.SwapBuffers();
```

I tried this by creating multiple contexts on the thread but it crashed with

> Error: 170" at "MakeCurrent()

of `glControl2`. (Even `glControl2.Context.MakeCurrent(null)` before switching the context didn`t work)

Maybe you have some hints which can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right after I posted this question I found the solution.

I created a new GraphicsContext on the thread I want to render my stuff.

```
//Here does a new thread start->
IGraphicsContext control2Context = new GraphicsContext(GraphicsMode.Default,glControl2.WindowInfo);
while(true)
{
    glControl1.MakeCurrent()
    //render
    GL.Flush();
    glControl1.SwapBuffers();

    control2Context.MakeCurrent(glControl2.WindowInfo);
    //render
    GL.Flush();
    glControl2.SwapBuffers();
}
```

As you can see, I'm not using `glControl2.MakeCurrent()`. Instead I created this new context `control2Context`.

Maybe this can help someone who is facing the same problem.

Comment: Please comment my answer if there is something wrong. If everything is fine, I´ll mark it as the answer.

Comment: can you please help me on this, I have already used above line of code. But still only one glcontrol is working at a time